# TypedActor vs ReceiveActor?

Tags: c#, akka.net

Most documentation refers to using `ReceiveActor` and then methods such as `Receive()`. However, some documentation refers to inheriting from `TypedActor` and then using interfaces such as `IHandle<MyMessageType>`.

Is it safe [as in, best practice/not deprecated] to use `TypedActor` + Interfaces or should I only be using `ReceiveActor`? (Official documentation seems to be unclear on the subject)

Answer (score 3):

`TypedActor` will be marked as obsolete in version 1.3, and will be removed in version 1.5 (relevant [pull request](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/pull/2723) and [issue](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/2557)).

There was [a discussion](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/221) a few years ago (as tomliversidge says in their answer) to rename it, but that plan didn't go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/221) with regards to this. Seems like it is being made obsolete in the Java/Scala Akka world so I'd probably stick to ReceiveActor unless TypedActor gives you something ReceiveActor doesn't

Comment: I am confused by the link as it also says that "TypedActor in Akka.NET is not the same as TypedActor in Akka.", so maybe they are making a different thing obsolete?

Comment: If you properly read that discussion, you'll see that they wanted to make it obsolete and add a differently named class with the same functionality, to avoid confusion. It doesn't look like they actually went through with it, though.